# Checking vectors for subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How to check if these sets are subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ ? i know the three condtions but how to check those conditions with some solvings? Thanks in advance......
$$U_1 = \{(x,y,xy)\mid x,y ∈ \mathbb{R}\}$$
$$ U_2 = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x+y-z = 0, 2x+y+z = 0\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you should solve the equations involved, then check that for each two solutions $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$, also $(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2,z_1+z_2)$ and $(kx_1,ky_1,kz_1)$ are solutions.

This could happen only if the equations are linear and homogeneous.

In the first example, the equation $z=xy$ is not linear, so this is not a subspace. The second one instead is a subspace.